# how to predict the time when event occurs

Tags: time-series, predictive-models

I have time series data. The data looks like the following:

```
ID  EVENT_TM
2   8:20:21
2   23:13:50
4   17:26:48
3   11:11:26
1   22:30:23
1   11:18:14
1   11:38:25
1   15:40:24
4   23:24:32
1   8:49:23
1   23:00:17
3   2:21:05
3   0:06:27
3   2:24:46
2   15:43:01
2   0:04:49
2   6:42:25
3   6:23:11
1   6:59:23
3   4:51:07
3   9:37:35
2   0:04:55
1   20:57:11
2   13:07:38
2   10:21:37
3   0:13:11
1   12:45:36
3   8:53:13
1   20:54:46
```

I also have date related information which i have not shared. Now I want to predict the list of top k most probable event happening time in a given day.

Comment: You could look into autoregressive conditional duration (ACD) model. It can be used to model time intervals between events.

Comment: Hi Richard, The ACD model is useful in case of continuous double auction. In my case the events are occurring due to one source only and lot of unknown factors are influencing it. Are there any ways to model this?

Comment: No, I don't have other ideas. I though you could still try ACD even if your setting is not a double auction, but you know better.